# Extract column headers from cell and rearrange columns accordingly

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-manipulation

I have a CSV file in (roughly) the following format:

```
Day   |  Asset Allocation     
0     |  NYSE:100+++FTSE100:143+++DAX30:94
1     |  NYSE:103+++FTSE97:143+++DAX30:95
2     |  NYSE:102+++DAX30:97
3     |  NYSE:102+++DAX30:97+++STOXX:102
```

So all assets are summarized in one column and separated by "+++". The order of the assets within the column can change as the CSV file progresses. I would like to rearrange the data to the following format:

```
Day  |  NYSE  | FTSE  |  DAX  |  STOXX
0    |  100   | 143   | 94    |  0
1    |  103   | 143   | 95    |  0
2    |  102   | 0     | 97    |  0
3    |  102   | 0     | 97    |  102
```

Preferably, I would like to be able to do it in Python, just because I do have some prior experience and might be able to find my way around more quickly. However, as the final dataset is likely to contain several million rows, I would of course be open to employ any other way that can handle the data more efficiently.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this efficiently with `pandas`.

This example uses `str.split` and regex to apply the necessary formatting.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def formatter(t):
    return re.sub('[0-9]','', t[0]), int(t[1])

def converter(x):
    return dict(formatter(i.split(':')) for i in x.split('+++'))

# read file
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='|')

# apply manipulations
res = df[['Day']].join(df['Asset Allocation'].apply(converter).apply(pd.Series))\
                 .fillna(0).astype(int)

print(res)

   Day  DAX  FTSE  NYSE  STOXX
0    0   94   143   100      0
1    1   95   143   103      0
2    2   97     0   102      0
3    3   97     0   102    102
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention unfortunately, that some cells are empty. Hence, I have been getting:

`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'`

When I add `.notnull()`  I get `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'split'`

Do you have any idea how I can solve this

Comment: Maybe drop null rows by "Asset Allocation" first? Look up dropna.